# Sympy.solve can't eliminate intermediate symbols from systems of equations

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, equation-solving

#### WHAT I WANT TO DO

I am building a DIY robot arm. I need to design the length of the links, the joint configuration, and motors size function of my working area and payload.

I decided it would be a fun project to make a program to help me with the task as it would help simulating the reach, and finding the forward and inverse kinematic matrices that control the robot.

I want the python program to be parametric, so i can define how many motors and links are present, how they are connected, and I want the python program to do three things:

- Plot me the reach with given parameters
- Find me the sensitivities of the end effector position in respect to the motor angles
- Compile the forward and inverse transformation matricies with given parameters

It's very simple to solve manually for two motors and two links, I want to try configurations and generally have fun with shapes and working areas, that's why I'm trying to make a more generic solver. For reference, this is the kind of construction that I want the program to provide the equations for:
[image]

#### WHERE I GOT SO FAR

I made a python program using the Sympy library to replicate what I do on paper: I define the equations of the mechanical system, individual joints and links and I get a system of equations, then use Sympy to solve the equations, both forward and reverse, scan and plot the position over given input angle range. It demonstrates that the Sympy solver can do what I need, solving a two joint system:

```py
import numpy as lib_numpy
# Import sympy library
import sympy as lib_sympy
#Display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create a symbolic 2D rotation matrix (2x2)
def create_rotation_matrix_2d( theta : lib_sympy.Symbol):
   return lib_sympy.Matrix([[lib_sympy.cos(theta), -lib_sympy.sin(theta)], [lib_sympy.sin(theta), lib_sympy.cos(theta)]])

#create a symbolic 2D vector 2x1 vertical x, y
def create_vector_2d( x : lib_sympy.Symbol, y : lib_sympy.Symbol ):
   return lib_sympy.Matrix([[x, y]])

#A segment is composed by a joint connected to a link
def create_segment( in_phi : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_theta : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_length : lib_sympy.Symbol ):
   #joints
   nnn_rotation_matrix = create_rotation_matrix_2d( in_phi +in_theta )
   #link from this joint to the next joint to come
   nn_link_vector = create_vector_2d( in_length, 0 )
   #equation of the link
   return nn_link_vector *nnn_rotation_matrix

def system():
   #---------------------------------------------------
   #   WORLD - J1
   #---------------------------------------------------

   eq_link_w_1 = create_segment( 0, 0, 0 )

   #---------------------------------------------------
   #   J1 - J2
   #---------------------------------------------------

   n_theta_1 = lib_sympy.Symbol('T1')
   n_length_1_2 = lib_sympy.Symbol('L1E')
   eq_link_1_2 = create_segment( 0, n_theta_1, n_length_1_2 )

   #---------------------------------------------------
   #   J2 - EE
   #---------------------------------------------------

   n_theta_2 = lib_sympy.Symbol('T2')
   n_length_2_e = lib_sympy.Symbol('L2E')
   eq_link_2_e = create_segment( 0, n_theta_1 +n_theta_2, n_length_2_e )

   #---------------------------------------------------
   #   END EFFECTOR
   #---------------------------------------------------
   #spawn the output of the system (referred to world)
   n_x = lib_sympy.Symbol('x')
   n_y = lib_sympy.Symbol('y')
   nn_end_effector = create_vector_2d( n_x, n_y )

   #---------------------------------------------------
   #   EQUATION
   #---------------------------------------------------
   #build the equation
   eq = lib_sympy.Eq( nn_end_effector, eq_link_w_1 +eq_link_1_2 +eq_link_2_e )
   print("Equation: ", eq )

   solution_forward = lib_sympy.solve( eq, [n_x, n_y], dict = True )
   print("num solutions: ", len(solution_forward))
   print("Forward Solution theta->x,y: ", solution_forward )

   #Construct equations from solutions
   for n_solution_index in solution_forward: #loop over the solutions
       #equation from solution so I can substitute
       equation_forward_x = lib_sympy.Eq( n_x, n_solution_index[n_x] ) 
       equation_forward_y = lib_sympy.Eq( n_y, n_solution_index[n_y] ) 

   print("Equation X: ", equation_forward_x )
   print("Equation Y: ", equation_forward_y )

   #---------------------------------------------------
   #   MAP THE REACH
   #---------------------------------------------------
   #   I initialize a "result" array. it contains the X and Y output
   #   I decide the minimum and maximum angle range of the joints
   #   for each solution
   #       first I set the length of the link, a parameter
   #       I replace the angle of the joints in the equation
   #       I solve the equation, and record the result

   #I initialize a “result” array. it contains the X and Y output
   result = []
   #samples
   n_steps = 8
   #Angles J1
   min = -lib_numpy.pi/2
   max = lib_numpy.pi/2
   nn_angles_j1 = lib_numpy.linspace( min, max, n_steps )
   #Angles J2
   min = -lib_numpy.pi/2
   max = lib_numpy.pi/2
   nn_angles_j2 = lib_numpy.linspace( min, max, n_steps )
   #link length
   in_length_1_2 = 5
   in_length_2_e = 3
   #scan angles for J1
   for n_angle_j1 in nn_angles_j1:
       for n_angle_j2 in nn_angles_j2:
           #I replace the angle of the joints in the equation
           n_eval_x = equation_forward_x.evalf( subs={n_theta_1: n_angle_j1, n_theta_2 : n_angle_j2, n_length_1_2 : in_length_1_2, n_length_2_e : in_length_2_e } )
           sol_x = lib_sympy.solve( n_eval_x, dict=True )
           #print("solution X: ", sol_x )
           n_eval_y = equation_forward_y.evalf( subs={n_theta_1: n_angle_j1, n_theta_2 : n_angle_j2, n_length_1_2 : in_length_1_2, n_length_2_e : in_length_2_e } )
           sol_y = lib_sympy.solve( n_eval_y, dict=True )
           #print("solution Y: ", sol_y )
           sol = [ sol_x[0][n_x], sol_y[0][n_y] ]
           #solve the now simple equation and get a number
           #print("solution: ", sol )
           #I solve the equation, and record the result
           result.append( sol )

   #---------------------------------------------------
   #   PRINT XY
   #---------------------------------------------------
   #   Print a scatter XY chart showing all the X,Y points
   #---------------------------------------------------

   #Print a scatter XY chart showing all the X,Y points
   x_values = [r[0] for r in result]
   y_values = [r[1] for r in result]
   plt.scatter(x_values, y_values)
   plt.xlabel("x")
   plt.ylabel("y")
   plt.title("Reachable points for a single link")
   plt.show()

#if execution detected
if __name__ == '__main__':
   system()
```

Output:

```
Equation:  Eq(Matrix([[x, y]]), Matrix([[L1E*cos(T1) + L2E*cos(T1 + T2), -L1E*sin(T1) - L2E*sin(T1 + T2)]]))
num solutions:  1
Forward Solution theta->x,y:  [{x: L1E*cos(T1) + L2E*cos(T1 + T2), y: -L1E*sin(T1) - L2E*sin(T1 + T2)}]
Equation X:  Eq(x, L1E*cos(T1) + L2E*cos(T1 + T2))
Equation Y:  Eq(y, -L1E*sin(T1) - L2E*sin(T1 + T2))
```

Forward End Effector XY map for some T1 T2 joint configuration
[image: Reach]

#### PROBLEM

Sympy only seems to be able to solve if there are no intermediate vars, which is baffling to me.

If I provide the full system of equations, Sympy.solve seems unable to see the equations M1X = 0 and M2X = M1X and eliminate the M1X symbol, even if I add it to the exclude list of the solver.

E.g. The following code:

```py
import numpy as lib_numpy
# Import sympy library
import sympy as lib_sympy
#Display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_rotation_matrix_2d( theta : lib_sympy.Symbol):
   return lib_sympy.Matrix([[lib_sympy.cos(theta), lib_sympy.sin(theta)], [-lib_sympy.sin(theta), lib_sympy.cos(theta)]])

def create_vector_2d( x : lib_sympy.Symbol, y : lib_sympy.Symbol ):
   return lib_sympy.Matrix([[x, y]])

def create_segment( in_phi : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_theta : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_length : lib_sympy.Symbol ):
   #joints
   nnn_rotation_matrix = create_rotation_matrix_2d( in_phi +in_theta )
   #link from this joint to the next joint to come
   nn_link_vector = create_vector_2d( in_length, 0 )
   #equation of the link
   return nn_link_vector *nnn_rotation_matrix

def create_segment_offset( in_start_x : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_start_y : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_phi : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_theta : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_length : lib_sympy.Symbol ):
   nn_offset = create_vector_2d( in_start_x, in_start_y )
   nn_segment = create_segment( in_phi, in_theta, in_length )
   return nn_offset +nn_segment

def create_segment_equations( in_length : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_start_x : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_start_y : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_phi : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_theta : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_end_x : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_end_y : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_end_theta : lib_sympy.Symbol ):
   l_equation = []
   #Segment X,Y equations function of angle
   equation_1 = lib_sympy.Eq( create_vector_2d( in_end_x, in_end_y ), create_segment_offset( in_start_x, in_start_y, in_phi, in_theta, in_length) )
   solution_1 = lib_sympy.solve(  [equation_1], [in_end_x])
   solution_2 = lib_sympy.solve(  [equation_1], [in_end_y])
   #Segment T angle equation function of angle
   equation_theta = lib_sympy.Eq( in_end_theta, in_phi+in_theta )
   #compose segment equations
   l_equation.append( lib_sympy.Eq( in_end_x, solution_1[in_end_x] ) )
   l_equation.append( lib_sympy.Eq( in_end_y, solution_2[in_end_y] ) )
   l_equation.append( equation_theta )
   return l_equation

def double_pendulum_system():
   #forward equations
   #T1,T2->EX,EY,ET
   l_equation = []
   #Motor 1 segment from World to its joint
   n_segment_1_length = lib_sympy.Symbol('L1')
   n_motor_1_theta = lib_sympy.Symbol('T1')
   n_segment_1_x = lib_sympy.Symbol('M2X')
   n_segment_1_y = lib_sympy.Symbol('M2Y')
   n_segment_1_theta = lib_sympy.Symbol('M2T')
   l_equation = l_equation +create_segment_equations( n_segment_1_length, 0, 0, 0, n_motor_1_theta, n_segment_1_x, n_segment_1_y, n_segment_1_theta ) 
   #Motor 2 segment from Motor 1 Joint to End Effector
   n_segment_2_length = lib_sympy.Symbol('L2')
   n_motor_2_theta = lib_sympy.Symbol('T2')
   n_end_effector_x = lib_sympy.Symbol('EX')
   n_end_effector_y = lib_sympy.Symbol('EY')
   n_end_effector_theta = lib_sympy.Symbol('ET')
   l_equation = l_equation +create_segment_equations( n_segment_1_length, n_segment_1_x, n_segment_1_y, n_segment_1_theta, n_motor_2_theta, n_end_effector_x, n_end_effector_y, n_end_effector_theta ) 

   print( "Equations", l_equation )

   #Forward Equation
   l_forward_solution = lib_sympy.solve( l_equation, [n_end_effector_x, n_end_effector_y, n_end_effector_theta],exclude=(n_segment_1_x,n_segment_1_y,n_segment_1_y,) )
   print( "Forward", l_forward_solution )

   #Forward Sensitivity
   #Sensitivity of End Effector X in respect to variations in T1 angle
   n_end_effector_sensitivity_x_t1 = lib_sympy.Symbol('EXdT1')
   l_equation.append( lib_sympy.Eq( n_end_effector_sensitivity_x_t1, lib_sympy.Derivative(n_end_effector_x, n_motor_1_theta) ) )
   l_sensitivity = lib_sympy.solve( l_equation, [n_end_effector_sensitivity_x_t1] )
   print("Forward Sensitivity", l_sensitivity )

   return

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print("TEST12")
   print("Forward density chart")

   #STEP1: compile forward equations
   double_pendulum_system()
   #STEP2: compile forward sensitivity, how sensitive is position to T1 and T2
```

unhelpful outputs:

```py
TEST12
Forward density chart
Equations [Eq(M2X, L1*cos(T1)), Eq(M2Y, L1*sin(T1)), Eq(M2T, T1), Eq(EX, L1*cos(M2T + T2) + M2X), Eq(EY, L1*sin(M2T + T2) + M2Y), Eq(ET, M2T + T2)]
Forward {EX: L1*cos(M2T + T2) + M2X, EY: L1*sin(M2T + T2) + M2Y, ET: M2T + T2}
Forward Sensitivity {EXdT1: Derivative(EX, T1)}
```

Which tells me that the derivative is the derivative, which is unhelpful to say the least.
The correct output I want to get is like:

```py
TEST12
Forward density chart
Equations [Eq(M2X, L1*cos(T1)), Eq(M2Y, L1*sin(T1)), Eq(M2T, T1), Eq(EX, L1*cos(M2T + T2) + M2X), Eq(EY, L1*sin(M2T + T2) + M2Y), Eq(ET, M2T + T2)]
Forward {EX: L1*cos(T1+ T2) + L1*cos(T1), EY: L1*sin(T1+ T2) + L1*sin(T1), ET: T1+ T2}
Forward Sensitivity {EXdT1: -L1*sin(T1)-L1*sin(T1+ T2)}
```

I tried *linsolve* to no avail, the equations are inherently trascendent, linsolve can't do anything with them.

#### QUESTION

1. How can I get Sympy.solve to sobstitute/eliminate unneded variables and get it to give me a closed solution?
2. is there anothe Sympy call or another way to properly symbolically solve the system of equations I provided in the example?

below a minimal snippet to replicate the problem in Sympy.solve

```py
#Try to solve X^2=Y+ReplaceMe for X with ReplaceMe=-1
import sympy as lib_sympy

def good( in_x : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_y : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_z : lib_sympy.Symbol ):
    equation = lib_sympy.Eq( in_x*in_x, in_y+ in_z )
    equation = equation.evalf( subs={in_z: -1} )
    solution = lib_sympy.solve( equation, in_x )
    return solution

#The solver doesn't realize that Z=0 and doesn't sobstitute
def bad( in_x : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_y : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_z : lib_sympy.Symbol ):
    l_equation = []
    l_equation.append( lib_sympy.Eq( in_z, -1 ) )
    l_equation.append( lib_sympy.Eq( in_x*in_x, in_y+ in_z ) )
    solution = lib_sympy.solve( l_equation, in_x, exclude = (in_z,) )
    return solution

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_x = lib_sympy.Symbol('X')
    n_y = lib_sympy.Symbol('Y')
    n_z = lib_sympy.Symbol('ReplaceMe')
    print("Manual Solution: ", good( n_x, n_y, n_z ) )
    print("Unhelpful Solution: ", bad( n_x, n_y, n_z ) )
```

Output:

```
Manual Solution:  [-sqrt(Y - 1.0), sqrt(Y - 1.0)]
Unhelpful Solution:  [(-sqrt(ReplaceMe + Y),), (sqrt(ReplaceMe + Y),)]
```

Comment: The explanation here and the code demonstrations are too complicated for the question being asked. I expect that you can write 10 lines of code to set up some example equations and call solve.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm preparing a snippet showing the problem.

Comment: I made a minimal snippet to replicate the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, when you call solve, you must tell it what variables to solve for. i.e. if you tell it to only solve for `x`, it will only solve for `x` -- and not for any intermediate variables...

There are a few things you can attempt. If you have a simple expression, such as you do in your toy example, you can simply use `Eq.subs` to substitute into your equation :

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

x, y, z = symbols('x y z')

equation = Eq(x*x, y + z)
equation = equation.subs(z, -1) # do the simple substitution
solution = solve(equation, x) # this equation has 2 variables, so we try to solve for one as a function of the other
print(solution)
# >>> [-sqrt(y - 1), sqrt(y - 1)]
```

otherwise, the more general approach is to solve for **all** your variables :

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

x, y, z = symbols('x y z')

equations = [
    Eq(x*x, y + z),
    Eq(z, -1)
]
solution = solve(equations, (x, z)) # this equation has 3 variables, so we try to solve for one as a function of the TWO others
print(solution)
# >>> [(-sqrt(y - 1), -1), (sqrt(y - 1), -1)]
```

This will output the value of your intermediate variables in the solution, but it's pretty trivial to strip it out with some post-processing.

Final extremely pedantic not : please follow usual conventions when writing your code. it makes reading and understanding your code much simpler for others (i.e. import libraries by their standard names, call symbolic variables by the same name as the code variables)

Comment: This works, for linear systems, thanks. For the convention, I strongly believe in scoping to avoid ambiguity in symbol resolution. E.g. matrix is a member of both Scypy and Numpy.

Comment: Fully agree -- scoping is a good idea as soon as you're working with more than one library. However, there are some conventions on how to name scopes, such as `import numpy as np`, `import scipy as sp`, etc... and if no convention exists or there is a risk of clashes, I would argue it's best to import the package explicitly (i.e. : `import math, numpy, sympy; math.sin(1); numpy.sin(1); sympy.sin(1)`), since these names are the ones that are commonly used and will be immediately recognized.